# Set CodeMirror style and addons with a html attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, codemirror

I have this CodeMirror (http://codemirror.net/index.html) text area:

```
<form><textarea id="code" name="code" codemirror-type='lineNumbers: false, styleActiveLine: true, matchBrackets: true;'>CODE HERE</textarea></form>
```

And as you can see I added the attribute "codemirror-type", I would like to set this style when the script is executed, I tried:

```
<script>
  var attrs = document.getElementById("code").getAttribute("codemirror-type");
  var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("code"), attrs);
</script>
```

But it does not work I suppose because it is not in the correct format (http://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#fromTextArea).

I really need to style the code editor from an HTML attribute (or class or addition tag or whatever) **How can I achieve this?**

Answer (score 0):

Solved, it was a JSON Parse issue, given a CodeMirror textarea like this:

```
<textarea id="code" name="code" codemirror-settings='{"lineNumbers": true, "styleActiveLine": true, "matchBrackets": true}'>CODE_HERE</textarea>
```

It can be rendered correctly like this:

```
var attrs = document.getElementById("code").getAttribute("codemirror-settings");
var obj = JSON.parse(attrs);
var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("code"), obj);
```